# Getting "Unknown provider: $qProvider <- $q" when fetching the defer/promise from my AngularJS injector

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am trying to create a simple example where I get the promise/defer object from AngularJS's service solution:

```
var $q;

function init() {

    var $injector = window.angular.injector();
    console.log($injector);
    $injector.invoke(["$q", function (_$q) {
        console.log($q);
        $q = _$q;
    }]);

}

init();
```

But it results in:

> Error: Unknown provider: $qProvider <- $q
>   [Break On This Error]
>   throw Error("Unknown provider: " + path.join(' <- '));

What could I have missed?

Comment: are u using this code from angular world or outside angular world

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to add which module the provider resides in like this:

```
var $injector = window.angular.injector(['ng']);
```

Then it will work!

**Edit:** Regarding the 'ng' module, the docs specifically says that it must be explicitly added. [From the angular injector docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.injector):

```
modules – {Array.<string|Function>} – A list of module functions or their aliases.
See angular.module. The ng module must be explicitly added.
```

Comment: it depends if injector is called from inside angular or outside angularjs

Comment: Outside angular, and do i have to provide a module? I can't get the defer/promise without defining angular-modules? Just curious.

Comment: You don't have to define your own module, 'ng' is angular's own module name, where e.g. the $qProvider is defined.
I tried this in the browser console and it worked: angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$q', function (q) { console.log(q); }]);

Comment: I will not work very well because $q use $rootScope and $rootScope is null if you don't bootstrap your your module. Asynchronous promises will never resolve for exemple.

Comment: I didn't think of that.. I don't see the point in using Angular without using modules.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/kriskowal/q if you're outside a angular.js module lifecycle, I've go down that road and it will not work well, $q is not meant to be used outside of a bootstraped module (require a $rootScope).